# Programa não realiza a contagem de pontos de maneira Correta

Tags: c

Nesse código devo ler o número de notas de 3 alunos comparar com um gabarito de 3 questões e verificar quantos pontos o alunos fez, porém só a nota do primeiro aluno aparece.

Segue o codigo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define tamanho 3
#define tamanho2 3
#define tamanhoVetor 3

int main()
{
    int matrizQuestoes [tamanho][tamanho2];
    int vetorGabarito [tamanhoVetor];
    int pontosAlunos [tamanhoVetor];
    int numeroAlunos [tamanho];


    int contador=1, soma=0;

    for(int i=1; i<=tamanho; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=tamanho2; j++)
        {
            printf("Digite a nota do aluno %d \n",contador);
            scanf("%d",&matrizQuestoes[i][j]);
            fflush(stdin);

            if(j%5==0)
            {
                contador+=1;
            }
        }
    }
     /*Vetor para o Gabarito*/

     for(int i=1;i<=tamanhoVetor;i++)
     {
         printf("Digite as respostas do Gabarito \n");
         scanf("%d",&vetorGabarito[i]);
         fflush(stdin);
     }

     /*Compara a Resposta com o gabarito*/
     for(int i=1;i<=tamanho2;i++)
     {
         pontosAlunos[i]=0;
         for(int j=1;j<=tamanho2;j++)
         {
             if(matrizQuestoes[i][j] == vetorGabarito[i])
             {
                 pontosAlunos[i]+=1;
             }
         }
     }

    /*mOSTRA A QUANTIDADE PONTOS*/
    for(int i=1;i<=tamanho2;i++)
    {
     printf("Pontos:%d\n",pontosAlunos[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse `if` interno, você está comparando todas as respostas de um aluno com o mesmo índice do gabarito, ao invés de comparar cada resposta com um índice diferente do gabarito:

```
 /*Compara a Resposta com o gabarito*/
 for(int i=1;i<=tamanho2;i++)
 {
     pontosAlunos[i]=0;
     for(int j=1;j<=tamanho2;j++)
     {
         if(matrizQuestoes[i][j] == vetorGabarito[i])
         {
             pontosAlunos[i]+=1;
         }
     }
 }
```

O correto seria utilizar o índice `j` e não o índice `i` no array `vetorGabarito`:

```
 /*Compara a Resposta com o gabarito*/
 for(int i=0; i < tamanho2;i++)
 {
     pontosAlunos[i]=0;
     for(int j=0; j < tamanho2;j++)
     {
         if(matrizQuestoes[i][j] == vetorGabarito[j])
         {
             pontosAlunos[i]+=1;
         }
     }
 }
```

Além disso, a linguagem C (assim como quase todas na verdade) utiliza arrays começando no índice zero. Ou seja, um array de tamanho 3 (e.g., `int lista[3]`) tem posições 0, 1, e 2.

Quando for percorrer um array usando laço `for`, inicie em 0 e vá até N-1 (onde N é o tamanho do array), como eu fiz no exemplo acima. Se não, você vai estar acessando uma posição inválida da memória, o que muito provavelmente vai causar erro em algum momento.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas, eu realmente não me atentei ao i imaginava que já que o ele contavas as linhas então iria comparar tudo, porém quando usei o índice com 1 pensei que por ter feito o com para conseguir mostrar a ordem dos alunos então deveria continuar com ele, mas como você disse então devo colocar tamanho+1?

Comment: Nao.Quando voce declara um array de N posicoes `int lista[N];`, cada posicao deste array eh acessada por um numero de 0 ateh N-1 (no seu caso, de 0 ateh 2). Ou seja, a primeira posicao do array eh acessada por comando do tipo `lista[0] = 10` e a ultima eh acessada por comando do tipo `lista[N-1] = 10`. Ou seja, como no seu caso os arrays tem tres posicoes, `vetorGabarito[0]`, `vetorGabarito[1]`, `vetorGabarito[2]` sao indices validos, mas `vetorGabarito[3]` nao eh. O mesmo vale para `matrizQuestoes` e `pontosAlunos`.

Comment: Em geral, se voce for percorrer todas as posicoes de um array voce deve utilizar o laco `for` da seguinte forma: `for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)`. Note, na primeira iteracao o `i` vai ser `0`, que eh o indice da primeira posicao do array, e na ultima iteracao o i vai ser igual a `tamanho-1`, que eh o indice da ultima posicao do array.